# Protobuf.net is taking more time to process compared to DataContractSerializer

Tags: silverlight, serialization, protobuf-net

I have a WCF  service consumed by silverlight application. To improve the performance of my application i considered using protobuf.net.

To support silverlight application, operation contracts have been modified to return byte[].

Protobuf.net version :v2.0.50727

After using protobuf.net serializer, message size has come down by 40%. 
However, it seems to be taking more time for processing compared to DataContractSerializer.

I believe byte[] is again getting serialized by DataContractSerializer and causing the delay. 
I have been testing the application on Windows 7.And measured time taken at server using fiddler. When serialized using protobuf-net, it seems to be taking couple of more seconds when compared to DCS. Any suggestions or ideas why it takes more time and how do I improve performance with protobuf-net? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On which platform is it slow? client or server? you mention Silverlight - is it the Silverlight part that is "slow"? how have you measured this "slowness"? etc? Happy to help, but need a little more context. What makes you concerned about DCS processing a `byte[]`? There isn't much you can do to pack a `byte[]`, so I would say it is entirely correct to pass that along unmolested...

Comment: I have been testing the application on Windows 7.And measured time taken at server using fiddler. When serialized using protobuf-net, it seems to be taking couple of more seconds when compared to DCS.

Comment: @Evangelist "on windows 7": but which platform? Full .net or sl?

Comment: @MarcGravell It was Full.net

Comment: @Evangelist ok; now: configuration wise - it sounds like you are handling the serialization manually to get a byte[]; is protobuf-net running as a WCF extension *as well*? Also: what sort of size byte[] do you have? What is the transport? Http? Http+MTOM? TCP? Basically, I need enough context to ideal repro what you are seeing, which does not sound like what I have typically seen.

Comment: @Mark Protobuf is not configured to run as WCF extension. My byte[] size is approximately 500 kb.  i have been using http as transport protocol.

Comment: Hi, sorry - I didn't get notified of that (because it is `@Marc`, not `@Mark`). It is really hard to diagnose from that, since that does not represent my experiences. Is there anything that I can use to get a repro to investigate?